# jQuery Arrays - Printing and Selecting

Tags: jquery, arrays, each

I was just reading up on push. I have a few questions regarding jQuery arrays.

1. How would I print/alert the contents of an array to check what is being pushed into them?
2. How do I call a particular key in the array?
3. Is there any decent documentation on jQuery arrays?

**EDIT:**

I'm not sure. I want to store a new variable in an array on a keyup event. So each time a user performs the event a position is stored as a new key in a variable. so later when another object enters that position a function is performed.

Arrays are the only way I can see this working?

Comment: Do you mean [**jQuery objects**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery) [a collection of DOM elements], *or* [**JavaScript arrays**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)?

Comment: There's no such thing as jQuery arrays :S

Comment: Or do you mean generic javascript objects (hashes, associative arrays)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print (or do something) with each item in an array you can use jQuery's `.each()` and to check if something is in an array `.inArray()`

As others have said there is no such thing as a "jQuery array".

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

```
var myArr = new Array();
myArr.push("hello");

alert(myArr[0]);

$.each(myArr, function(index, value) { 
  alert(index + ': ' + value); 
});

// Will alert the index or -1 if not found.
alert($.inArray("hello", myArr));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, just do `alert(array)`.
2. You can get a particular index of an array with `array[index]`.
3. There is no such thing as a jQuery array, but [MDN has excellent documentation on Javascript arrays.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)